Why does the volume comes out to be $\pi\frac{a^3}{8}$ instead of $\frac{3\pi a^3}{8}$?
Find the volume of the solid inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2-2ay=0$ and between $z=0$ and the paraboloid $4az=x^2+y^2$ equals $\frac{3\pi a^3}{8}.$
I tried solving the  problem as follows:
The equation of the cylinder can be rewritten as $x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2.$ Now, the paraboloid and the cylinder intersects at the plane $4az=2ay\implies y=2z.$
So, the required volume is given by $V=\int\int\int_EdV,$ where $E$ is the solid region mentioned in the question. Now, $V={\int\int}_D\int_{\frac{x^2+y^2}{4a}}^{\frac y2}dV\implies \int\int_D\frac{x^2+y^2}{4a}-\frac{y}{2}dA,$ where $D$ is the disk given by $x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$ in the $xy$ plane.
Now, the integration would've been really easier if we translate all the surfaces by $a$ units to the left and also that won't change the volume. For then, the cylinder is $x^2+y^2=a^2$ and the paraboloid is $4az=x^2+(y+a)^2.$
So, the intersection between them is given by the equation $4az-2ay=2a^2\implies 2z-y=a\implies z=\frac{a+y}{2}.$
Let us call the new solid region $E'$ and the disk in the $xy$ plane as $D'.$
Thus, $V=\int\int\int_{E'}dV=\int\int_{D'}\int_{\frac{x^2+(y+a)^2}{4a}}^{\frac{a+y}{2}}dzdA=\int\int_{D'}(-\frac{x^2+(y+a)^2}{4a}+\frac{a+y}{2})dA=\int\int_{D'}\frac{a^2-x^2-y^2}{4a}dA.$
Converting to polar coordinates, we have, $V=\frac{1}{4a}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^aa^2r-r^3drd\theta=\frac{1}{4a}\int_0^{2\pi}[a^2\frac{r^2}{2}-\frac{r^4}{4}]_0^a=\frac{a^4}{4.4a}2\pi=\frac{a^3}{8}\pi.$

However, my answer is not $3\pi\frac{a^3}{8}.$ I am unable to find the mistake in my solution. It will be very helpful if someone please point it out.

In general, questions of the form "Where did I make a mistake?" are not really appropriate for this website.  Keep in mind that that goal of the SE network is to create a repository of questions and answers, which are likely to be useful to many other people.  Having the community here "grade your homework" is highly unlikely to be of use to anyone but you.  As such, this question is really "too local" for this site, and I am closing it as such.

The bounds for $z$ are$\int_0^{\frac{x^2+y^2}{4a}}$, not $\int_{\frac{x^2+y^2}{4a}}^{\frac y2}$.

@AnneBauval Why?

This is the specification of your solid.

Just use polar coordinates without translating. It's about time to learn that the off-center circles $x^2+y^2=ax$ and $x^2+y^2=ay$, respectively, are given by $r=a\cos\theta$ ($-\pi/2\le\theta\le\pi/2$) and $r=a\sin\theta$ ($0\le\theta\le\pi$), respectively.

Or simply: $\int_0^a\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(r\cos t)^2+(a+r\sin t)^2}{4a}dt\right)rdr=\dots$
